# What does kth largest/smallest element mean?

Tags: algorithm

I'm currently studying selection algorithms, namely, median of medians.

I came across two following sentences:

> In computer science, a selection algorithm is an algorithm for finding
>   **the kth smallest number** in a list or array;
>
> In computer science, the median of medians is an approximate (median)
>   selection algorithm, frequently used to supply a good pivot for an
>   exact selection algorithm, mainly the quickselect, that selects the
>   **kth largest element** of an initially unsorted array.

What does kth smallest/largest element mean?
To make question a bit more concrete, consider following (unsorted) array:

```
[19, 1, 7, 20, 8, 10, 19, 24, 23, 6]
```

For example, what is 5th smallest element? And what is 5th largest element?

Comment: If you sort the array from smallest to largest, the 5th smallest element is the 5th element in the sorted array. The 5th largest element is the 5th from the end in the sorted array. 10 is the fifth smallest, 19 is the fifth largest.

Comment: Was the question just wanting to clarify what "kth" meant in that context?

Comment: I wish someone would just describe what `the kth element` means instead of saying how to find it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you sort the array from smallest to largest, the *k*th smallest element is the *k*th element in the sorted array. The *k*th largest element is the *k*th from the end in the sorted array.  Let's examine your example array in Python:

```py
In [2]: sorted([19, 1, 7, 20, 8, 10, 19, 24, 23, 6])
Out[2]: [1, 6, 7, 8, 10, 19, 19, 20, 23, 24]
```

The smallest element is 1, second smallest is 6, and so on. So the *k*th smallest is the *k*th element from the left. Similarly, 24 is the largest, 23 the second largest, and so on, so the *k*th largest element is the *k*th element from the right. So if *k = 5*:

```
In [3]: sorted([19, 1, 7, 20, 8, 10, 19, 24, 23, 6])[4]  # index 4 is 5th from the start
Out[3]: 10

In [4]: sorted([19, 1, 7, 20, 8, 10, 19, 24, 23, 6])[-5] # index -5 is 5th from the end
Out[4]: 19
```

Note that you don't *have* to sort the array in order to get the *k*th smallest/largest value. Sorting is just an easy way to see which value corresponds to *k*.

Comment: There are plenty of algorithms for the th element that don't require sorting, so whilst it would be in that position if you do sort, that is not quite what the term means. For small  you can just keep the  greatest so-far elements in memory as you iterate the array.

Comment: @PeteKirkham I understand what you're saying and possibly I'll reword my answer, but "kth smallest" is exactly equivalent to the "kth value in the sorted array", regardless of whether or not you sort to get it, and OP was not asking about algorithms, but a definition. Considering OP wasn't sure what "kth smallest" meant, I think my current answer is clear in describing that.